# Define global namespace/variable within a TypeScript module

Tags: module, namespaces, typescript, global, webpack

In TypeScript I can define a global/top-level namespace and use it in another file like so:

```ts
namespace foo.blah {
    export function baz() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```

And in another file, this works:

```ts
foo.blah.baz();
```

However, if I then import something from another module:

```ts
import Thing from 'boo';

namespace foo.blah {
    export function baz() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```

Suddenly my whole file is a module, the `foo.blah` namespace is local, not global, and the `foo.blah.baz()` call in the other file fails. `export namespace ...` just causes the namespace to become part of the module's export, not a global.

Is there a way to write a TypeScript file which imports from other modules but also defines global/top-level symbols?

At the moment I'm doing this:

```ts
import Thing from 'boo';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

namespace foo.blah {
    export function baz() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

$.extend(true, window, {foo});
```

Which works, but the TypeScript compiler still can't see that `foo.blah...` exists as a global in other files.

(The file is the entry point for Webpack, and I'm trying to import things from other modules in the Webpack bundle and assign them to globals so they can be used in `<script>` tags on the page.)

Answer (score 3):

When you add the `import`, you switch from internal modules to external ones, as the spec says:

> In external modules, relationships between files are specified in
>   terms of imports and exports at the file level. In TypeScript, any
>   file containing a top-level import or export is considered an external
>   module.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-going-external

The philosophy behind external modules is to avoid global objects, why don't you create a new module with `foo.blah` (and all the stuff you need) and import it as TypeScript expects it?

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to define global variables for use in `<script>` tags inside the page, using what is exported by other modules. (The application is over a decade old and I'm trying to incrementally move it to pure TypeScript.)

Comment: If you want to slowly migrate then why don't you use `.d.ts` files (e.g.  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/ace/ace.d.ts) and then just use references like this `///<reference path="relative/path/to/file.d.ts" />`?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to declare namespace in global.

```
declare global {
  namespace foo.blah {
     function baz() {
       console.log('hello');
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This yields compiler error `An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.`. The `declare` keyword designates an ambient context, which means that the given entity does not exist in runtime, only in TypeScript.

Comment: what is 'global', a file?

Answer (score 1):

create a [`global.d.ts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html) and put your type there

reference: [cannot use d.ts file to load declaration merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66418579/cannot-use-d-ts-file-to-load-declaration-merging)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was to call the `google-one-tap` library from a module. The library is only available as script, but a types package exists: `@types/google-one-tap`.

Code snippet from the types package `@types/google-one-tap/index.d.ts`:

```
export as namespace google;

export const accounts: accounts;

export interface accounts {
    id: {
        initialize: (idConfiguration: IdConfiguration) => void;
        disableAutoSelect: () => void;
[...]
```

As you can see in the above declarations file, there is a namespace `google` that contains objects/interfaces.

My code calling the library from a module:

```
google.accounts.id.initialize(...)
```

Without the fix (see below) the above code returns an exception when building: `error TS2686: 'google' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`

To be able to see the types and to get successful compilation, I declared a variable for the namespace `google` as follows. There is no code generated for declarations.

```
declare var google: {
  accounts: google.accounts
};

// Now this works without errors.
google.accounts.id.initialize(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of this is actually not recommended and red flags [per documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#do-not-use-namespaces-in-modules). Moreover it says that:

> Multiple files that have the same export namespace Foo { at top-level (don’t think that these are going to combine into one Foo!)

That being said, I also had to preserve namespaced construct when migrating to ES6 modules because some systems don't offer a simple way to suddenly change namespace references like find & replace (MS Power Apps for example) or maybe you are really developing a library and want to preserve the entry point `foo`

If you had different first part of namespace per file, this would be enought:

```
(window as any).foo = foo
```

But having multiple, each file would overwrite previous `window.foo`

But there are ways what you can do when migrating to modules. With some webpack configuration, namespaces CAN be exposed as a public variables.

```
/* 
  Merge foonamespace between multiple files and expose it as a global variable. Otherwise foo namespace stays as module scoped variable.

  exports global variable foo (because library.name is foo), and it uses a construct that:
  - Copy the return value to a target object if it exists, otherwise create the target object first: Basically copies foo.* to foo object. This turns out to be a merge of namespaces.
  - Namespace MUST BE exported.
  - export: 'foo' means that instead of having global variable foo.foo.blah I have foo.blah (basically this should be the value whatever namespace starts with) 

*/
output: {
  ...
  library: {
    name: 'foo', //or [name] if you have namespace same as entry point name
    type: 'assign-properties' //or var or window if same namespace doesn't span multiple modules
    export: 'foo'
  },
}
```

There are many more ways to expose stuff to global scope (different `type` values available). [Refer to webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary)

P.S. A module (having import or export statement) means variables get scoped as a module (rightly so) and that brings these challenges in the first place to preserve namespaced construct. [Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

> Modules are executed within their own scope, not in the global scope; this means that variables, functions, classes, etc. declared in a module are not visible outside the module

P.S.2 How does webpack achieve it? The output looks something like:

```js
var __webpack_export_target__ = (foo = typeof foo === "undefined" ? {} : foo);
var __webpack_exports_export__ = __webpack_exports__.foo;
for(var i in __webpack_exports_export__) __webpack_export_target__[i] = __webpack_exports_export__[i];
if(__webpack_exports_export__.__esModule) Object.defineProperty(__webpack_export_target__, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

Implication is second level namespace must be unique.