# cannot use d.ts file to load declaration merging

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

works fine perfectly when these are in the same file.

```
declare module "express-session" {
    interface SessionData {
        userId: number;
    }
}


static async loginUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    req.session!.userId = 1;
    return res.send("login");
}
```

However, if I seperate these files into,

index.d.ts
index.ts

then it shows that userId does not exist within SessionData or Partial.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 3):

Try to put your declaration into `global.d.ts`. See the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html)

AFAIK, global.d.ts should be in the root directory.

If you want to put it into sibling file `index.d.ts`, please update [typeRoots](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) or [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types)

Comment: tested just now, `global.d.ts` doesnt need to be in the root directory